# Count Occurrences of Substrings in One Column in Second Column R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

How do I split column a (by the space character) and count how many times any of the substrings in column a exist in column b?

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

dt = data.table(
    a = c('one', 'one two', 'one two three'),
    b = c('zero', 'none_or One?' , 'onetwothree')
)
```

I failed when I tried:

```r
dt[ , .(
    str_count( b,
        pattern = str_split( a , pattern = ' ' )
    )
) ]
```

```
Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I expect:

```r
   V1
1:  0
2:  1
3:  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another couple of variations:

With just *data.table*:

```
dt[, mapply(\(sp,txt) sum(sapply(sp, \(x) grepl(x, txt))), strsplit(a, " "), b) ]
##[1] 0 1 3
```

With *data.table* and *stringr*:

```
dt[, mapply(\(sp,txt) sum(sapply(sp, \(x) str_detect(txt, x))), strsplit(a, " "), b) ]
##[1] 0 1 3
```

Comment: Whoa, your code looks awesome, but I get an error with your code: `Error: unexpected input in "dt[, mapply(\"`

Comment: You might have an old version of R that doesn't allow `\(x)` as a replacement for `function(x)`  - try: `dt[, mapply(function(sp,txt) sum(sapply(sp, function(x) grepl(x, txt))), strsplit(a, " "), b) ]`

Comment: Yes... I am working on a very, very old machine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dict = paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(dt$a, " "))), collapse="|")
f <- function(s,dict) {
  res = gregexpr(dict,s)[[1]]
  return(ifelse(res[1]==-1,as.integer(0),length(res)))
}
dt[,f(b, dict), by=.(1:nrow(dt))][,.(V1)]


   V1
1:  0
2:  1
3:  3
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to create a regex, then apply the regex to each object.

Try this:

```
dt [, parsed:= str_split(a, " ")]  
dt [, regex := lapply(parsed, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "|"))]
dt [, V1    := mapply (function(x,y) {str_extract_all(x,y)[[1]] |> length()}, b, regex)]
dt [, .(V1)]
```

Comment: Interesting. I have never used mapply. I get an error when I try to run your script: `Error: unexpected '>' in "dt [, V1    := mapply (function(x,y) {str_extract_all(x,y)[[1]] |>`

Comment: Did you mean to pipe the result, like with `%>%`?

Comment: Try `dt [, V1    := mapply (function(x,y) {length(str_extract_all(x,y)[[1]])}, b, regex)]`.

Comment: `|>` is R pipe operator. Or, as suggested by @TMo, you can use %>%, in this case3 you should use `library(magrittr)`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
dt[, sum(sapply(tstrsplit(a, " "), function(x) grepl(x, b))), .(a, b)]
```